# re-sizable SVG animation

Tags: browser, svg

I have an animation which is 1920*1200, and I need this animation to be re-sized to the viewing window size. And the animations should work without a problem when the window is smaller. Is there any solution for that. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to use a ['viewBox'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute, perhaps together with ['preserveAspectRatio'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).